# How to compute head pose estimation?

Tags: python, opencv

So I would like to make a game where you control the character using your head with Python.
But, all of the tutorials I have found so far doesn't seem to be 2D. I just like to know the position of the face and its angle. Is there any tutorial/modules that can do this without too much coding?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no, there is no way to do a generic head pose estimation in general**. This is a [nice tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-head-pose-estimation-in-python-e52db1bc606a) on the subject which explains some of the current limitations and constraints. The biggest problem you will have is in getting a robust, diverse, well-sampled dataset in a variety of conditions suitable to your use case.